next.js reverse proxy with nginx/1.27.0 using docker-compose - 502 Bad Gateway
I am having problem setting up nginix with https  as a reverse proxy for my next.js app.
I am running this on EC2 Linux/UNIX (Amazon linux )
this is my setup:
nginx.conf
events {}
    
    http {
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name mydomain1.com mydomain2.com mydomain3.com;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    
        server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name mydomain1.com mydomain2.com mydomain3.com;
    
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain1.com/****.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain1.com/*****.pem;
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://app:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
        }
    }

Dockerfile for next.js app
FROM node:18-alpine
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the entire project to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the Next.js application for production
RUN npm run build
# Set the environment variable to run the Next.js application in production mode
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]

docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: username/docker_hub_repo_name
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - web
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    driver: bridge

Output for docker ps is
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                      NAMES
ba2ea4bc2931   nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   next-js-app-nginx-1
1fd8e63f5585   ******/next-app     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp                          next-js-app-1

But, when I run
docker logs docker_id (of my next app docker id ) I get
> next start

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Local:        http://localhost:80

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 683ms

I am running next.js on port 3000 but it seems that this 2 docker container talk to each other on port 80.
If I put 80 as a port for my next.js app then I get this error
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint next-js-nginx-1 (0e63bdb3c2d0392d80758d10ccdd7b4a2ae741b4ef6e188e9c9cff37bde6f04c): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

I can not run  next.js on 80 and nginx on 80 witch make sense !!
EC2 security group Inbound rules (3)
sgr-******  IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   –
–
sgr-******  IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   –
–
sgr-******  IPv4    SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0

What am I missing here!!!
Thanks in advance

docker containers (nextjs and nginx) are communicating over 80 port. and I was proxying over 3000 port. A way to check it, you will "log in" to you docker with
docker exec -it docker_id_or_name  sh
and then do a crul comand ,
curl http:localhost:3000 and you will get nothing, but if you do
curl http:localhost:80 you will get your nexjs app.
So if nginx.config I added
upstream nextjs {
 server app:80;
}
location / {
      proxy_pass http://app:3000;
      proxy_pass http://nextjs;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

and from docker-compose I have removed all
networks:
   web
networks:
   web:
     driver: bridge

docker-compose now do networking by default on port 80 I think
